# Http POST drops port in URL

Tags: django, apache, nginx

I have a webapp built with Django. I'm currently running it off a laptop at home behind a router.

I have the router configured to route all traffic sent to a specific port to that laptop.

I have Nginx as a reverse proxy for Apache, using mod_wsgi to run Django.

My problem is this: when I try to submit any POST form, the port # gets removed from the url (e.g. 209.245.23.201:1552/login/ becomes 209.245.23.201/login/)

Naturally, this breaks. What causes this (Nginx, Apache, Django?) and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: It appears that the forms DO submit, but I think the redirect fails.

EDIT 2: The problem is definitely either with Nginx, or the interaction between Nginx and Apache. I tried the setup with Apache as the only server, running django, and it worked fine. So either Nginx is dropping the port, or somehow Apache is getting confused by Nginx acting as the proxy.whatever

Comment: silly questions... how do you know that the port number is dropped? How did you find out?

Comment: It literally gets removed from the url in my address bar.

Comment: This might be a browser issue. What browser are you using?

Comment: Definitely sounds like the redirect is at fault. We'd have to see the code that actually causes that redirection in order to possibly tell you why it does that.

Comment: It's not the browser. I tried both Chromium and Firefox.

Django is doing a redirect after logging in, but that's just 
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard/').

It's not a problem when I'm running the Django test server, it only happens when I connect via Nginx and Apache.

Comment: Well, if it's coming back to your browser, that would mean that it did the round trip, but somehow the port number got lost when arriving to the server, or on the way back, right?

Are your requests actually reaching Django? Are you able to test that? If you submit something, is there a way that Django leaves a log or a trace of that activity?

Comment: Django doesn't keep logs, but I checked Nginx's and Apache's logs. It looks like this is what is happening:

I send login info via post to (example ip) 209.245.23.201:1552/login/.
Django logs me in, and then returns HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard/').
Up until that point, everything is okay.

Then, somewhere along the line, the browser is told to go to 209.245.23.201/dashboard/ instead of 209.245.23.201:1552/dashboard/.

My router only forwards stuff on 1552 to my server, so it spits out a 404.

Comment: Does HttpResponseRedirect interact in some way with the Sites framework?

Comment: I don't know. I can't find any indication in the docs. I don't think the problem is in Django, because the Django test server works fine with a port other than 80.

If I run the test server on 0.0.0.0:80 I can connect from outside my network just fine with my router doing all the forwarding.

Comment: To see the Nginx and Apache configuration files couldbe helpful

Comment: Reverse proxies frequently rewrite urls to match themselves; does Nginx have the port configured correctly in the rewriting rules? (/me is not an Nginx expert...)

Comment: Techside's answer below solves this with a one line change to your site's nginx configuration in the /sites-available/ directory. Forget the requests for more info, just scroll down ;)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I have the same problem with my development server.
After some internet search I've found this discussion ([nginx, apache, and odd admin error](http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg89789.html)) where the solution is to modify the proxy configuration of nginx.

The configuration setting to modify is:

```
proxy_set_header            Host $host;
```

the solution is to add the port number:

```
proxy_set_header            Host $host:$server_port;
```

In my ngnix + apache2 (with worker mpm) + django now all works well.

Comment: I was having the exact same problem with my home dev environment and this solved it. This should be the accepted answer for this question.

Comment: In my case $server_port was not being resolved and I had to put my server_port manually ("$host:8080").

Comment: Thanks Techside, this is great.
I'll add that I had to do the same as Amit, when running Nginx+Django in Vagrant, where Vagrant mapped external:8000 to internal:80, and nginx was proxying internal:80 to django at internal:8000. $server_port not resolved, possibly due to being 80 on nginx.

Comment: I had the same issue with NGINX and gunicorn, and the above answer fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, you would also probably need to clean cached redirect from your browser.

Comment: Same issue with multiple django/gunicorn/nginx sites in the same docker machine (different containers). This made the trick

Answer (score 10):

You want to pass on the original HTTP Host header, which arrived at nginx:

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

This appears to be a bug with the default configuration of nginx in Debian/Ubuntu, which uses only `$host`: `$host` will not contain the `$server_port`.
(This is configured in `/etc/nginx/proxy_params` for the Debian/Ubuntu package, and you might override it in your configuration after including it.)

Please note that `$host:$server_port` is different from `$http_host`.
See http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24host for an explanation.

Reported and fixed in Debian: http://bugs.debian.org/733016

Comment: This solves my problem. The accepted answer does not

Comment: This one is definitely the way to go. I was tunneling through a Vagrant instance so my port was different on the nginx server, the Django server and my browser's side.

Comment: Pardon the noob question, but where in the nginx config does the proxy_set_header line go?  Inside the location block? After the listen line?  Somewhere else?  Thanks!

Comment: I got the "proxy_set_header Host $http_host;" solve my nginx, gunicorn, django

Comment: using $http_host solved my problem. I was running nginx under debian (the oficial docker image)

Answer (score 6):

Given everything you're concerned with is clear HTTP (unlike something like AJP for instance) I'd run a protocol analyser such as Wireshark on the host and determine at which point the redirect is introduced.

Answer (score 2):

Check the error logs.  On Linux mine are at /var/log/apache2.  Just running a search for error.log should turn it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you find that this occurs with a url derived from the get_absolute_url() method of a model, you should use pass that path to [HttpRequest.build_absolute_url()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) in order to prepend the hostname and port to the path.