# django admin redirects to wrong port on save

Tags: django, nginx, port

I have a django project set up with nginx+apache. The http port for outside access is 20111 which is then forwarded to the server machine (which has an internal IP) to port 80. So nginx listens on port 80 (and passes relevant requests to apache on port 5000).

Now the initial login can be reached from the outside via http://externalip:20111 - but when I complete an admin action, like saving an entry, I get redirected to http://externalip/path/to/model -- without the port 20111. The result is a timeout. How can I tell django to use a specific hostname/port (i.e. http://externalip:20111) for all admin redirects?

Comment: I think your Site (http://externalip:20111/admin/sites/site/) does not have the port in its domain field.

Your site domain appears to be "externalip" rather than "externalip:20111". Is this correct ?

Comment: I'm not using the Site framework. Are you saying that if I enable it, it will automatically make the admin framework use the Site.domain on all redirects?

Comment: OK, I tried using the Site framework now, I am including the port in the domain field and I set SITE_ID to the correct ID, but the admin still redirects me to the base url without the port 20111.

Comment: So the admin uses the view 'shortcut' from django/contrib/contenttypes/views.py to do the redirect. According to the code, line 61 "object_domain = get_current_site(request).domain" decides what domain to use, as such: http.HttpResponseRedirect('%s://%s%s' % (protocol, object_domain, absurl)) (where absurl is the return value of get_absolute_url.

I recommend that you debug this view (http://blog.yourlabs.org/debugging-python-and-django-code can help) and figure where is the domain coming from.

(I assume you restarted the server, if you didn't then please do so)

Comment: Hmm the 'shortcut' function never seems to get called. Instead, the redirect url for e.g. "save and continue editing" is constructed in contrib/admin/options.py, line 828: "return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)" - request.path being /appname/model/id.

Comment: Sorry for my strange commend, actually i misunderstood and investigated for a possible issue in the "View on site" object-tools link which appears when you define a get_absolute_url. I'm taking another look. What version of Django do you have ? Also, forgive this stupid question but: did you try with another browser ? Apart from "View on site", I don't know any case where django admin would redirect to a full url including the domain... It redirects to relative paths all the way.

Comment: I found the solution. I found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391986/http-post-drops-port-in-url . The poster had the same issue, and almost the same solution worked for me, except that nginx could not resolve $server_port, so I entered the port directly: proxy_set_header Host $host:20111; -- anyway, many thanks for your help!

Comment: Fantastic job pholz +1 for your perceverance.

Answer (score 3):

When deploying applications behind a proxy or load balancer, it is common to rely on the [X-Forwarded-Host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers) header. Django has [support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST) for it

First of all, you have to setup nginx to send the proper headers. Add to your nginx host configuration (inside your `location` section):

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:20111;
```

Second, add to your settings.py:

```
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
```

It will allow django to trust `X-Forwarded-Host` headers from a request.

It should make it work for you. For security reasons, you should not trust every value sent in `X-Forwarded-Host`, so add your trusted domains/IPs to [ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) in `settings.py`